# How can I update the ID column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, auto-increment

My question may seem easy to answer for some people but I can't find an answer.

So in SQL Server Management Studio I have a column of Ids (primary key) with an increment of 1.

By making a mistake I find myself in the situation where my id's run of 23 to 36! and not 23 to 24 ...

[image]

How to restore the default incrementing ?

Thanks in advance for you answers and best regards !

Comment: Why does it matter if they aren't numbered correctly? Does the Id have an identity associated with it? If you ever delete and re-add one in future, you'll be in the same position again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **RESEED** function to setup your identity column
Check this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)